# JWT and nodejs returns invalid token as a response after signin

Tags: node.js, angular, express, express-jwt

I'm using nodejs/express and express-jwt module.
this is the server code involved:

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.hash)) {
        if(user.accountActive === true) {
            const {hash, ...userWithoutHash} = user.toObject();
            const token = jwt.sign({sub: user.id}, config.secret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
            console.log(token)
            return {
                ...userWithoutHash, token
            };
        } else {
            throw 'Your account is pending approval.'
        }
    }
}

function jwt() {
    const secret = config.secret;
    return expressJwt({ secret, isRevoked }).unless({
        path: [
            // public routes that don't require authentication
            '/users/authenticate',
            '/users/register',
        ]
    });
}
```

i am having `{message: "Invalid Token"} message: "Invalid Token"` whenever i tried to make a call to any api within the app 
[image]

Here is the request header: the token is not added to the request headers
[image]

i add the authorization header with jwt token if available on the localstorage

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
            }
        });
    }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
```

when i login the url logs in and sends the token to an authenticate post route

```
// routes
router.post('/authenticate', authenticate);

module.exports = router;

function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    userService.authenticate(req.body)
        .then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'username or password is incorrect' }))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

Here is an example of the authenticate login session request after signin
[image]
it seems like jwt token even though its valid it becomes invalid after signin.
to me it seems like a token issue, but i don't know where the problem at exactly?

**N.B I finally found where the problem was , i did not add the jwt interceptor to my app.module 
by adding the bellow code to the providers fixed it for me:**

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
```

This mean that for the token i am providing a value, more than one value (or class) is going to be used.

angular-cli: 8.3.0
node: 10.16
express: 4.17.1
express-jwt: 5.3.1

Comment: Are you passing authorization token in header, in below format `Authorization:Bearer <your JWT token>`?

Comment: i add authorization header with jwt token if available on the local storage. I updated the question above and added the intercept

Comment: have you checked if the token is really added to the headers ? You can check this in network tab of console.

Comment: How config.secret value is set? Also you can attach a debugger in vscode to debug code line by line.

Comment: @NS23 on config.json there are 2 strings the connection string and secret this way {
    "connectionString": "server**",
    "secret": "sharedddddddddd-secret"
}

Comment: @krishnasapkal the token is not added to the header it is send with the response

Comment: Did you checked in chrome developer tool network tab, whether correct token is being sent?

Comment: @Ivawen we are asking  check if your interceptor is working . Check the request you are making to the server in the network tab of browser console and find headers in the payload and check if token is added there or not. In the `request` you are making not response.

Comment: @krishnasapkal No the token is not being added to the request headers, sorry for the confusion, i edited the question and added the request headers